# How can I sort a string list in Python with two criterias at the same time?

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

Given I have a string list in Python:

```
list = ["   banana   ", "Cherry", "apple"]
```

I want to sort this list to be case insensitive AND ignore the whitespaces. So like this:

```
list = ["apple", "   banana   ", "Cherry"]
```

If I use this:

```
sorted(list, key=str.casefold)
```

I get this:

```
list = ["   banana   ", "apple", "Cherry"]
```

It's case insensitive, but the space character comes before the letters.

If I use this:

```
sorted(list, key=lambda x:x.replace(' ', ''))
```

I get this:

```
list = ["Cherry", "apple", "   banana   "]
```

It ignores the spaces but is not case-insensitive. I've tried to combine the two solutions, but I couldn't make it work. Is there a way to fix this easily and "merge" the two results?

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name

Comment: Beside the point, but `list` is a bad variable name since it [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the [builtin `list` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list). It's better to use a more descriptive name like `fruits`, or at least something like `lst`. Cf. [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable](/q/31087111/4518341).

Comment: I don't actually use this list or this list name. It's just an example.

Comment: Still, avoid it. In example code, it's just confusing.

Comment: I needed a couple of extra constraints and used a regex as well in the end, but this was a good start! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) for removing spaces from the beginning and end of string and use [`str.casefold()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) for caseless sorting.

```
lst = ["   banana   ", "Cherry", "apple"]

res = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x.strip().casefold())

print(res)
```

Output:

```
['apple', '   banana   ', 'Cherry']
```

Answer (score 3):

Just chain the calls

```
values = ["   banana   ", "Cherry", "apple"]
print(sorted(values, key=lambda x: x.replace(' ', '').casefold()))
# ['apple', '   banana   ', 'Cherry']
```

To only discard spaces at the beginning and end, I'd suggest `str.strip`

```
print(sorted(values, key=lambda x: x.strip().casefold()))
```

Answer (score 0):

An older question, but I'd like to give an alternative answer for future reference that uses **PyICU** instead, and can be used with any supported locale, making it a more flexible solution.

With Unicode based collations, it is possible to tailor the collation in a white number of ways. Whitespace are variable collation elements, and it is possible to selectively change how they are processed. It is possible to shift their collation weights, and process them at a quaternary strength rather than at a primary strength. This will enable the necessary sort behaviour required by the OP.

We will:

1. Create an PyICU Locale object
2. Create a collator instance
3. Use the collator sort keys to sort a list

It is possible to build an ICU locale that tailors aspects of the collation for that locale using BCP-47 **U** extensions.

The `ka` subtag allows us to control how variable collation elements are processed. For Alternate shifting, we use `-u-ks-shifted`. WE can also use the `kv` subtag to restrict which characters are shifted.

The required language tag is `en-u-ks-shifted-kv-space`.

```py
import icu
fruit = ["   banana   ", "Cherry", "apple"]
locale = icu.Locale.forLanguageTag('en-u-ka-shifted-kv-space')
collator = icu.Collator.createInstance(locale)
sorted_data = sorted(fruit, key=collator.getSortKey)
print(sorted_data)
# ['apple', '   banana   ', 'Cherry']
```